# Hom of sheafification

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, presheaves

Let $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ be presheaf of modules. Can we say that there exist a bijection between $\hom(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})$ and $\hom_{\mathrm{sheaf}}(\mathcal{F}^{\sharp},\mathcal{G}^{\sharp})$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  You've asked about a problem that can be resolved by reasoned mathematical arguments, but you omitted (in your very terse presentation) such *context* for the Question as where you encountered the problem, what makes it important or challenging, etc.  A little context improves the Question for future Readers, and posts without context are often closed through Community Review.

Answer (score 2):

No. As a simple example, consider the empty space $X = \emptyset$. Then every module defines a presheaf on $X$, but only the zero module defines a sheaf on $X$. In particular every sheafification gives the $0$ sheaf. Therefore we also only have trivial morphisms of sheaves on the level of sheafifications, but may have non-trivial morphisms before passing to the sheafification.

The "right" bijection one has is the one coming from the sheafification being the left adjoint of the forgetful functor. So there is always a natural bijection

$$\text{Hom}_{\text{Sh}}(\mathcal{F}^{\sharp},\mathcal{G}) = \text{Hom}_{\text{PSh}}
(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})$$ for every presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ and every sheaf $\mathcal{G}$. In particular, we have a natural bijection
$$\text{Hom}_{\text{Sh}}(\mathcal{F}^{\sharp},\mathcal{G}^{\sharp}) = \text{Hom}_{\text{PSh}}
(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}^{\sharp})$$
if $\mathcal{G}$ is a presheaf.